# Why do some questions in question lists have a yellow background?

Tags: discussion, questions, design

On SO, when I'm scrolling through "questions" some have a yellow background.  Is this intuitive to everyone but me?  What is the yellow background trying to tell me about this particular question?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The questions highlighted in yellow have tags you have marked as watched. Questions appearing grayed out you have marked as ignored. You can manage these either on the front page or on the preferences page of your profile.

Comment: Wow.  That's great.  Although it wasn't intuitive to me when I saw the color.  I wonder if a tooltip or something is warranted here?

Comment: Was pretty intuitive for me =/

Comment: totally non-intuitive to me. I specifically came to meta today to find out why this was happening.

Comment: Non-intuitive for me also.

Comment: I also came to meta today just to find out about the yellow background (and imported my account just to leave this comment). At first I assumed that they were newer questions or questions with less satisfactory answers.

Comment: I too had to come here and find out why some of the questions were highlighted.  Now it makes sense.

Comment: Non-intuitive. Just searched Google to find an answer to this question.

Comment: Obvious now I read this, totally wasn't before

Comment: I just tried to upvote this answer, then found I voted it already 3 years ago. So not only is it not intuitive, it's not memorable :(

Comment: Are we sure this is correct. I have the tag "css" added as a favorite and I've posted a question that is tagged with "css".  When I navigate questions with the "css" tag, my question is white, when I navigate to "html" where my question also shows up, it's yellow.

Comment: I browse only my favourite tags but still a subsection gets highlighted yellow. This seems to be when the question contains 2 out of 3 of my tags.

Comment: Did anyone else thought it indicates question got Flagged and waiting for moderation?

Comment: **Unintuitive** what yellow means.  **Unuseful** indicating favorites here. **Unstable** what this feature is even called: used to be called "favorite", or "interesting", now it's called "watched". **Unstable** where you control it: used to be able to change this set of tags from the profile, now it's on each tag page.

Comment: **MISSING PIECE:** When you are browsing questions of a tag that you are following, that tag's questions are not highlighted yellow. The yellow highlighted ones have OTHER tags that you also follow. Here I see that flutter-only tagged questions are not highlighted even if I follow flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

Answer (score 34):

There are two reasons a question can be marked as yellow.

### Favorite tags

You can add favorite tags from the main page, or the prefs page (Link to prefs above bio in profile). They get highlighted on all pages (except for their own tag pages).

[image]

You can also *ignore* a tag, and it will grey out/disappear (depending on prefs and the page). Note that ignored tags have preference over favorite tags. In the example above, a question tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) will be greyed out.

### Frequented tags

If you post on a tag often, and have a good enough score, the system decides you like the tag and auto-highlights it. This is only if you have not specified any other favorite tags.

Of course, it can lead to this{*}:

[image]

If you really don't want to choose favorite tags, then add some random nonsense tag to the list. SOmewhere on MSO, I saw [frequentedtagsfail](/questions/tagged/frequentedtagsfail) used for this, so I use it as well.

[image]

<sup>*That *did* happen to me. I was besieged by enticing yellow QM questions that I didn't know a thing about.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Those questions have tags that you have marked as interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Conversely, the tags which you mark as ignored will be grayed out.