# Why some questions have yellow background when I am viewing under my interesting tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/under-questions-why-are-some-with-a-yellow-background) answered my question "why some questions has yellow background" but it raised another question.
I am viewing questions under my interesting tag then what is the need for yellow background because all questions fall under my interesting tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593), if you're viewing questions by tag, then the question should only be highlighted if they contain another interesting tag as well.

Comment: My question is why any of the questions should be highlighted because, I know I am browsing by my interesting tag. So it shouldn't highlight any questions. Here is a quote from one of the comments from "Jeff Atwood": - '@fred we'll try to improve this so when you're browsing by tag it's not highlighting'. Actually that is what I am thinking should be. Thanks for sharing that question.

Comment: @gbs, I understand what you're saying. Even though they're all part of your interesting tags, I guess its just so that you can spot questions that might be of even more interest to you because they match more than one tag :P You could always make a feature-request or leave a comment on Jeffs answer suggesting it be removed entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Although you are viewing questions that you are interested in (or tags that you are active in) there are questions in there that you aren't interested in.

If you are logged in you will see 9 questions (18 for anonymous users) that are picked by random from the last 3000 questions.

Hence, why most of them are highlighted but 9 of them won't be as you haven't marked the tag as interesting.

[image]

[Recent changes to the homepage](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)