# Can we have a legend for the colors and icons on question list pages?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [under questions, why are some with a yellow background?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/under-questions-why-are-some-with-a-yellow-background)

Some questions have an orange background on the Stack Overflow main page.

The exact meaning of the background color is not immediately clear to a new user like me; I can tell only that it is not about the question being recent, or having an answer, or votes.

Maybe it would help to put a small legend at the bottom of the page for that coloring, for bounties and for other icons.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/under-questions-why-are-some-with-a-yellow-background), but I'm not going to vote to close since you had a feature-request in here too

Comment: @Popular Hey now, don't go making my close vote useless!

Comment: @Adam but how else will I interfere with your pleasant day?

Comment: @Pop A poke in the eye with a sharp stick works well enough.  Low tech, sure, but there's nothing like a poke in the eye with a sharp stick to get you going in the morning.

Comment: I think icons and the colors are really great on the stack sites - they make things easier to read quickly. User friendly. But they also could make things worse if their meanings are ambiguous. Personally, I think you will retain more new users if ambiguous icons have a footer legend. PS Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are questions having tags, which are determined to be interesting to you (either automatically -- frequented tags or you've have selected them as favorite tags).

I do agree that it's not obvious and needs some kind of indication. IMHO small icon with tooltip would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to update your answer now that the question is changed...

Comment: So they are questions with tags that match my "favorite tags". Thanks vartec.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't.  The footer is already large enough.  If we start adding stuff to it that rightly belongs in the FAQs here on meta, it will become unwieldy, and worse - people will still come here asking about things because, as we all know, people don't read.