# Why are there different colors for certain StackOverflow questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, questions, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [under questions, why are some with a yellow background?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/under-questions-why-are-some-with-a-yellow-background)
>   [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

What do the different colors (top 3 beige rows) for the questions on [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) mean?

I'm guessing it means the question is tagged with with one of my *favorite* tags, but I can't find a definitive answer.

Thanks!

[image: Stack Overflow Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those highlighted questions are tagged with at least one of your Favorite tags (shown on the right in the image above).